# Parse a Website that contains AJAX with Python - Which libraries?

Tags: python

I want to parse different websites which contain Javascript / JQuery / AJAX. What options do I have in Python?
I have seen several different libraries, but I want to know, which is the best to go for?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can always use [selenium](http://selenium-python.readthedocs.org/en/latest/) / [splinter](http://splinter.cobrateam.info/) with the [xvfb](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Xvfb) ;)

**your_bash_script.sh:**

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
set -e
xvfb-run --server-args="-screen 0 1024x768x24" python your_parse_script.py
```

Comment: +1, But go headless with [PhantomPy](https://github.com/niwibe/phantompy), not need for X.